# driver.findElement(By.linkText("")) working in one test but throwing exception in another

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to write two testng tests in the same class (using Selenium webdriver) - one logs in into the application and the other creates a new account.

These are the steps I am following
- use @BeforeClass to open the application on firefox browser

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.salesforce.com";
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
}
```

- First test to login into the website

  ```
  @Test
  public void testLogin() throws Exception {
  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(strUsername);
  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(strPassword);
  driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
  ```

  }
- Second test to create a new account

  ```
  @Test
  public void createAccount() throws Exception {
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Accounts")).click();
  ************************
          ************************
          ************************
          ************************
          ************************
  ```

  }

My problem is that when I run this testng test, I get exception in the second test:
**org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Accounts"}**

But if I include the command "driver.findElement(By.linkText("Accounts")).click();" in the testLogin() test, it works. I want to run all my tests in the same browser session.

Any input would be appreciated much.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@BeforeClass runs just once for a class.  So, if you are keeping both your tests in the same class, the order of execution is @beforeClass , your first testcase  and then your second testcase(Your accounts link should be visible by the time you reach to this test).

The order of tests is not gauranteed.  So, if the accounts link is visible only after you login, then it may not be that your cases pass all the time.  So, the issue may be

1. the element is not appearing by the time your createAccount() test is reached
   or
2. createAccount is invoked before login, due to which the accounts link is not available.

If you want your testcases to execute in a particular order, then use dependsOnMethods and make createAccount dependent on testLogin method. (Refer [Testng Dependent methods](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods))

Comment: Thanks niharika_neo. The createAccount was running before testLogin so I was getting the exception. Using dependsOnMethods solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@BeforeClass will run your setup method for each individual test - so for test 1, a new Firefox browser will be created and it will login. For the second test, another new Firefox browser will be created and it will try to find the Accounts link - which I assume is only shown when you are logged in, however the second browser will not be logged in at this point.

Are you sure you are after @BeforeClass?

Comment: In testng, the tests run in the same browser window but the createAccount() method was getting invoked before login() so it was throwing the exception. Using dependsOnMethods solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your 2nd test method is being executed first. It needs to execute 1st method (for login) to get the "Accounts" link. You need to use dependsOnMethod in 2nd method so that testLogin will execute 1st and then createAccountMethod. Your setUp() method seems to be OK with @BeforeClass. So, leave setUp() method unchanged. Declare Other two methods as:

```
@Test
public void testLogin() throws Exception {
//your code here
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods{"testLogin"})
public void testCreateAccount() throws Exception {
//your code here
}
```

In the above code testLogin() will execute 1st and then testCreateAccount() method so that your desired link to click will not miss